# 'date' is not defined in python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am using tkinter and when I try to run my code it gives error that " 'date' is not defined". Here is short short piece of my code.

```
def creation():

    def makefile():
        f = open(".\{}\{}.txt".format(date,date),"w")
        f.write(input())
        f.close()

    def create_a_note():
        date = cal.selection_get()
        cal.destroy()
        root.destroy()
        os.mkdir("{}".format(date))
        print("please input your note")
        input_box = tk.Text(height=10,width=50)
        input_box.pack()
        ttk.Button(text="okay",command=makefile).pack()
```

Comment: Try adding `global date` at the start of both functions.

Comment: Just add `global date` on start of `create_a_note()`.

Answer (score 3):

This is an issue with global and local scopes. Even though the functions `makefile` and `create_a_note` are both in the function `creation`, the variables defined in each one belong to separate scopes. There would be two ways I can quickly think of in order to solve this issue.

### 1. Accept the variable as a parameter

This would be my recommendation, as you would not have to worry about functions re-assigning values to the original variable. By passing `date` as a parameter to `makefile`, you can avoid this possibility while still being able to reference whatever is stored in `date`.

```py
def creation():
    def makefile(date):
        f = open(".\{}\{}.txt".format(date, date), "w")
        ...

    def create_a_note():
        date = cal.selection_get()
        ...
        return date

    date = create_a_note()
    makefile(date)
```

### 2. Use date as a global variable

This does work just as well, but you do have to be careful that you do not assign a value to `date` which you did not intend to.

```py
def creation():

    def makefile():
        global date
        f = open(".\{}\{}.txt".format(date, date), "w")
        ...

    def create_a_note():
        global date
        date = cal.selection_get()
        ...
```

Comment: Why do we need `global date` inside `makefile()` ?

Comment: Actually I now realize that OP does not assign any new values to `date` inside `makefile()`, so it wouldn't be necessary.